# ls won't display Cyrillic characters properly

Tags: terminal, osx, ls, character-encoding

I've got a problem with Cyrillic alphabet. My terminal will display Cyrillic normally as well most of my programs the only exception I've found so far is `ls`. Instead of normal Cyrillic it displays `?????? ???`.

I am Running macOS Mojave.

Screenshots included.

[image: terminal]
[image: finder]

Comment: If you unset all the `LC_*` variables does it start working? (Try `unset $(set | sed -n '/^LC_/s/=.*//p')` and then `ls`). If so, it's a locale issue.

Comment: It was indeed problem with locale. I've had LANG set to en,  unsetting LANG and LC_ALL fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

```
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Explanation: 
First, make sure you have the correct locale installed :

```
locale -a | egrep -i 'ru.*utf'
ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Then you can try to set your correct locale. My first try would be:

```
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

And you can make a simple test:

```
( date; export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 ; date +%c)
Fri Mar  8 08:08:50 -03 2019
пятница,  8 марта 2019 г. 08:08:50
```

Then you can make a slightly(?) more complex test:

```
( date; \
    export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 ; \
    d=$(date +%c | sed 's/ /_/g'); \
    mkdir /tmp/test; \
    echo $d > /tmp/test/$d.txt; \
    echo "with right locale:"; \
    ls -ltra /tmp/test ; \
    echo "with 'C' locale:"; \
    LC_ALL=C ls -ltra /tmp/test )
Fri Mar  8 08:14:19 -03 2019
with desired locale:
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 мар  8 08:13 пятница,__8_марта_2019_г._08:13:21.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 мар  8 08:13 пятница,__8_марта_2019_г._08:13:38.txt
drwxrwxrwt 19 root    wheel 608 мар  8 08:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 vfalcao wheel 160 мар  8 08:14 .
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 мар  8 08:14 пятница,__8_марта_2019_г._08:14:19.txt
with 'C' locale:
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 Mar  8 08:13 ??????????????,__8_??????????_2019_??._08:13:21.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 Mar  8 08:13 ??????????????,__8_??????????_2019_??._08:13:38.txt
drwxrwxrwt 19 root    wheel 608 Mar  8 08:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 vfalcao wheel 160 Mar  8 08:14 .
-rw-r--r--  1 vfalcao wheel  48 Mar  8 08:14 ??????????????,__8_??????????_2019_??._08:14:19.txt
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think that locale names are case dependent, so `ru_RU.UTF-8` rather than `ru_RU.utf-8` (this doesn't seem to matter on macOS though).

Comment: Well, my example was made in a Mac. It worked with lowercase `utf-8`. Just to be sure, I'll uppercase it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the locale to one that can handle UTF-8 characters. The `C` locale cannot (will not) do so.

One option is to remove the `LC_*` environment variables that are forcing the locale to be `C`, but it would be better to address the underlying issue and set them correctly in the first place.

```
unset $(set | sed -n '/^LC_/s/=.*//p')
```